# Matlab: How to plot the image of some points that are connected, and preserve that connection

Tags: matlab, plot

So let's say I have some points in three dimensional space, x1,x2,...xn, and I plot them so that x1 is connected to x2, x2 is connected to x3, and so forth.

First, how do I do this?

Next, I have a function f that takes points in 3-space and returns points in 3-space, and I want to plot the image of these points such that f(x1) is connected to f(x2), f(x2) is connected to f(x3), and so forth.

What's the Matlab code that can preserve these connections?

Comment: Have you looked at `plot3` or `scatter3` for example?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are just searching for something simple like [`plot3`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html). The points are connected by default. If you want to show the data-points, you can use [`linespec`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) to easily define the style of the points and the line.

```
x = [1,2,3; 2,3,4; 3,3,5; 7,3,6];
plot3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),'*-');
grid on;
```

*This is the result:*
[image: pic1]

Here is an example that calculates new points with the function `newpos`. After this, the modified curve is plotted in the same figure.

```
function example

x = [1,2,3; 2,3,4; 3,3,5; 7,3,6];

plot3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),'*-');
grid on;

for i = 1:size(x,1)
    x(i,:) = newpos(x(i,:));
end

hold on;
plot3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),'d-');


function y = newpos(x)
y = x + [1 2 1];
```

*The result looks like this:*
[image: pic2]

Comment: Does Matlab connect two adjacent points in the array x? So if I apply some function f to all the points in x and plot this, the image of two connected vertices in the original array will still be connected?

Comment: @MaxLipton The `plot3`-function just takes the values out of the `x`-matrix. They are connected by default. If you change the values and then plot it again, they are connected again... in the order of appearance in `x`.